# Create a file with logs after Impala query execution

Tags: hive, impala

I have a script with 8 impala queries in order to run them through airflow. I want to create a log file when the script finish, to display fetched rows, execution time, and some logs. Is this possible and how can I achieve that?

Comment: what did you do and where are you stuck? I assume, you can put impala scripts in  views and then write insert overwrite script and store in a file one after another. call that script using another shell script which uses impala-shell command to call first script.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I want inside the script I have, at the end to take some information about the procedure (execution time, fetched rows, etc) and create a file with these.